# When do two non-measurable sets have the same inner and outer measures?

Tags: probability-theory, measure-theory, outer-measure

Let $(X, \mathcal X, \mu)$ be a finite measure space with $\mu(X)=1$. Let $\mu^*$ and $\mu_*$ be the outer and inner measures, respectively, induced by $\mu$.

A simple fact is

> For all $A,B \in X$, if $\mu(A \triangle B)=0$, then $\mu(A)=\mu(B)$.

I am trying to generalize something like this to non-measurable sets.

> Is it true that if $\mu^*(A \triangle B)=0$, then $A$ and $B$ have the same inner and outer measures?

I have been able to show that in this case the outer measures of $A$ and $B$ must be the same, but I don't see that it holds for their inner measures.

In case it doesn't hold for the inner measures, is there another way of generalizing the simple fact above for non-measurable sets?

Comment: I think it may help to replace $A$ and $B$ by their complements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You already know that $\mu^\star(A\triangle B)=0$ implies that $\mu^\star(A)=\mu^\star(B)$. Now apply this to $A^c$ and $B^c$, together with the nice identity $A\triangle B=A^c\triangle B^c$, to conclude that $\mu^\star(A\triangle B)=0$ also implies that $\mu^\star(A^c)=\mu^\star(B^c)$, which implies that $\mu_\star(A)=\mu_\star(B)$ by subtracting both sides from $1$.

There are many ways to prove the key identity $A\triangle B=A^c\triangle B^c$, one approach is to observe that
$$
A\triangle B=(A\cap B^c)\cup (A^c\cap B),
$$
and replacing $A,B$ by their complements just switches the sets in the left group of parentheses with those in the right group - so the union remains unchanged.